# Programmatically Changing a XML file?

Tags: android, xml, screen

I have a XML file that I set up to tell the app what image to use as the splash screen. However, I have multiple images that can be used depending on the screen size. I have the following code to determine the screen size:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Note: I'm using getWidth and getHeight because my app is using API 7. I do know that they were deprecated later on.

Anyways, here is what I have in my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Basically, what I want to be able to do is be able to programmatically change splash_screen to whatever the name of my file is depending on the screen size. Any ideas how I can change the XML file from my code?

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: You haven't specified what language and what platform.

Comment: Language? I'm assuming you mean programming language. It's an android application so Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do it manually. Resource qualifiers do this for you, so you can always refer to a resource by a single name.
Check the information and examples available at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Answer (score -1):

If this is in your resources, you **CANNOT** modify your resources at run time. Only thing you can do is programatically build your layout/styles.

Comment: The attribute I want to change is located within the resources element. The XML file itself is located within res/values

Comment: which I just said you CANNOT modify your resources. Read above.

Comment: When asking the question, I was unsure exactly what I was trying to ask. The resource qualifiers that dtmilano pointed out was what I was thinking of at the time I asked my question. I apologize for asking the question incorrectly.